# Can an abstract shape have color?

Tags: difference

In Korean, words meaning ‘red circle’ and ‘big circle’ are semantically correct, but in English ‘circle’ just means shape, so is ‘red circle’ a wrong expression because colour is not a quality of shape?

Comment: A "circle" can have a range of meanings, including both the abstract geometric shape *and* an actual instance of a circle (drawn on paper, for example). That second sense can be adjectivally modified, as in *a **small** circle, a **red** circle*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, I was sad because I thought a downvote means a question is ill-written.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your question. My comment is only a *guess* as to what might help you understand exactly why there's nothing wrong with ***a red circle***. It might be that it's easier for someone else here *who knows Korean as well as English* to explain things in a way that makes sense to you.

Comment: Is it relevant that in English we can't normally talk about something like ***a red region of empty space*** because regions of empty space cannot have a "colour" attribute? Whereas we *can* refer to a ***small*** region of empty space, because all "regions" have "size".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes! It’s relevant.

Comment: It might be useful to think about some other words that can refer to "abstract" (non-physical, "conceptual") referents, as well as actual physical manifestations of an abstract concept. For example, in most "geometric" contexts, ***radius*** is an abstract concept referring to a straight line drawn from the centre of a circle to the perimeter, so you couldn't normally talk about ***a metal radius***. But in geometry, a ***spoke*** usually refers to "a real-world instance of a radius", and it's fine to talk about ***a metal spoke*** (or even a short spoke, or a red spoke).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not wrong. I draw red circles often. They draw attention to areas of the screen capture.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "*Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.*" - It's always possible to construct a grammatically correct and yet utterly nonsensical sentence.  A "*red region of empty space*" could qualify as such, but might even be valid in certain contexts.  E.g.: in some video games, you can glitch and fall through the terrain into an un-rendered void, often blue or black, but no reason it couldn't be red or any other color.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: I was specifically thinking of that "region of space" as being located somewhere in ***outer** space* rather than *"**cyberspace**"*. But even there I suppose "virtual quarks" would be constantly popping into existence and vanishing (and as I recall, quarks have a "colour" attribute, so maybe that wasn't the best choice of example! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "circle" can refer to the abstract idea of a circle. But it can also be used to refer to a specific object, a circle drawn on a piece of paper or painted on a wall, or an object that is in the shape of a circle.

Thus, it is perfectly correct to say, "I drew a large blue circle on a piece of paper."

This is true of many words in English. For example, I can say, "I like chocolate" or "Chocolate is made from cocoa beans", using "chocolate" to refer to chocolate in general, the abstract idea of chocolate. I can also say,  "I ate an entire box of chocolates", referring to a specific set of candies made of chocolate.

I don't know any Korean so I have no idea how that language works. Is it not possible in Korean to say, for example, "A circle has a circumference equal to pi times the diameter" or the like? That is, to talk about circles as an abstract mathematical concept without talking about any particular circle that someone has drawn or an object that is shaped like a circle? As I say, I don't know Korean. Maybe there are different forms of the word or some such. Or maybe you're just having difficulty relating concepts in your native language to the same concepts in another language.

Comment: Yes, in Korean, abstract noun circle can be modified by red or big. Even there’s no concrete noun circle

Comment: @yahae I think you're confused about what "abstract" and "concrete" mean. If you point to a circle painted on the wall and say "That is a red circle", then you are using "circle" as a concrete noun. You are referring to a specific object: the painted circle. If you are talking about the geometrical properties of a circle in mathematical terms, it would be meaningless to say "red circle". We don't say "a red circle has a circumference equal to pi times the diameter". This would be true of any actual circle regardless of its color.

Comment: Actually, your second example with ‘chocolate’ is a generic noun, not an abstract noun. You’re not talking about the concept of chocolate, but of chocolate as a material or foodstuff in a collective sense.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Fair enough. Bad example.

Answer (score 3):

A circle *is* a shape, and a shape can be a property of something else (for example, 'a circular place mat' is a place mat that is circular in shape). However, 'circle' is a noun and can be assigned properties of its own, such as colour. So, there is nothing wrong with saying "a red circle", especially if there is nothing else to say about the item other than it is a circle.

If "circular" was the property of another item (lets stay with the place mat example) and it was also red, [guidelines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) suggest that the shape would come before the colour (ie a circular, red place mat).

Comment: You mean for example ‘red shape’ is valid?

Comment: @yahae yes... in the right context. When something is not a recognisable shape (for example, an ink blot) we sometimes call it "a shape", and it might be red. You could also use 'shape' as a broader term, for example if you had different shapes (circles, squares, triangles etc) of all different colours and you wanted to sort them by colour, you could say "put the red shapes on the left and the blue shapes on the right".